# How can I output text for only one ggplot bar while inside a dplyr chain?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Here's some data (called carrier):

```
        Age Term   Band Gender Class Premium
4568  31-35   30 Band 3 female   PNS      26
3033  18-30   20 Band 1 female  SPNS     285
1035  18-30   20 Band 3   male  SPNS     576
145   18-30   20 Band 1   male  PPNS     168
2626  18-30   10 Band 3 female   SNS      47
4617  31-35   10 Band 1 female  SPNS     187
2246  18-30   30 Band 2   male   PNS     723
3677  18-30   30 Band 1   male   PSM     569
259   18-30   30 Band 4 female  PPNS     675
397   18-30   15 Band 4   male  PPNS      91
1485  18-30   10 Band 4 female  SPNS     204
3459  18-30   10 Band 1   male  SPNS     467
8805  46-50   20 Band 2 female  SPNS     365
1316  18-30   20 Band 2 female   PNS     311
11379 56-60   20 Band 1   male  SPNS     370
7284  41-45   15 Band 1 female   SSM     590
4360  31-35   10 Band 4   male   SNS     109
1318  18-30   20 Band 2 female   SNS     191
6131  36-40   15 Band 1 female   PSM     722
4501  31-35   20 Band 4   male  PPNS     704
8656  46-50   10 Band 2   male   SNS     587
1045  18-30   20 Band 4   male  PPNS     398
4341  31-35   10 Band 2 female  SPNS     419
2623  18-30   10 Band 3 female  PPNS     729
9668  51-55   20 Band 2 female   PNS     689
3532  18-30   15 Band 1   male   SNS     763
4363  31-35   10 Band 4 female  PPNS     567
260   18-30   30 Band 4 female   PNS     401
8086  46-50   10 Band 2 female   SNS     202
3385  18-30   30 Band 1   male  PPNS     292
169   18-30   20 Band 3   male  PPNS     185
2452  18-30   20 Band 1   male   SNS     665
5362  36-40   20 Band 3 female   SNS     772
1020  18-30   20 Band 1 female   SSM     616
5643  36-40   20 Band 3   male  SPNS     627
13544 61-65   10 Band 1 female   PNS     612
6359  36-40   10 Band 2 female   PSM     508
6295  36-40   30 Band 3 female  PPNS     597
5564  36-40   15 Band 2 female   PNS     356
2603  18-30   10 Band 1 female   PSM     740
2774  18-30   20 Band 4   male   PNS     425
4405  31-35   15 Band 2   male  PPNS      18
5003  31-35   15 Band 3 female   PSM     168
3567  18-30   15 Band 4   male  SPNS     499
5268  36-40   15 Band 1 female   SSM     636
6772  41-45   20 Band 1   male   SNS     262
5866  36-40   15 Band 3 female   SNS     438
5337  36-40   20 Band 1 female  SPNS     384
3471  18-30   10 Band 2   male  SPNS     429
5620  36-40   20 Band 1   male   SNS     527
```

and this is my dplyr/ggplot code:

```
carrier%>%
group_by(Age)%>%
summarise(high=length(which(Premium>300)),low=length(which(Premium<300)))%>%
gather(key,value,-Age)%>%
ggplot(aes_string("Age","value",fill="key"))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack",na.rm=TRUE)+
geom_text(data=. %>% filter(key=="high"),aes(label=sum(value)))
```

and the output I get here is:
[i don't want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYmne.png)

So 35 is the sum of all high values for all age groups. It doesn't really make sense for me to output that for every column. I would like to output 35 only once, but I cannot figure out how I can do this. I should also mention that this code is within a Shiny app where "carrier" is an input. What I have tried so far is:

```
carrier%>%
group_by(Age)%>%
summarise(high=length(which(Premium>300)),low=length(which(Premium<300)))%>%
gather(key,value,-Age)%>%
ggplot(aes_string("Age","value",fill="key"))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack",na.rm=TRUE)+
geom_text(data=. %>% select(filter(key=="high"),value),aes(label=sum(value)))
```

> Error in key == "high" :    comparison (1) is possible only for atomic
>   and list types

and

```
carrier%>%
group_by(Age)%>%
summarise(high=length(which(Premium>300)),low=length(which(Premium<300)))%>%
gather(key,value,-Age)%>%
ggplot(aes_string("Age","value",fill="key"))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack",na.rm=TRUE)+
geom_text(data=. %>% filter(key=="high") %>% select(value),aes(label=sum(value)))
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Age' not found

,but both return an error. I'm still a beginner to ggplot/dplyr, so I'm not quite sure what is happening here. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Where are you trying to print `35`?

Comment: I would like to print in the top right corner, but as long as it's in a reasonable place on the output (can be inside or outside plot), I'm ok with it.

Comment: `> length(which(carrier$Premium>300))
[1] 35`

Comment: Huh. It should be 50 unless we're looking at different things. Are you perhaps not scrolling down all the way?

Comment: Ah, you're right, apologies. Still don't think you need to complicate it with summarise though, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell it specifically where you want `geom_text`, otherwise they are treated like labels for your `geoms`.

```
carrier %>%
  group_by(Age) %>%
  summarise(high=length(which(Premium>300)),low=length(which(Premium<300))) %>%
  gather(key,value,-Age) %>%
  ggplot(aes_string("Age","value",fill="key")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack",na.rm=TRUE) +
  geom_text(x = 7.5, y = 23.5, data=. %>% filter(key=="high"),aes(label=sum(value)))
```

[image]

Alternatively you could set it up as a `grob`. http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-texts-add-text-annotations-to-a-graph-in-r-software

```
numbers <- carrier %>%
  group_by(Age) %>%
  summarise(high = length(which(Premium>300)),low=length(which(Premium<300))) %>%
  gather(key,value,-Age) %>%
  filter(key == "high") %>%
  summarise(sums = sum(value))

grob <- grobTree(textGrob(numbers, x=0.85,  y=0.95, hjust=0,
                      gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=13, fontface="italic")))

p + annotation_custom(grob) #where p is your plot
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that you actually want to `group_by` and `summarise` here; rather, I think you just need a simple `if_else`:

```
df_summary <-
  carrier %>%
  mutate(
    high_low = if_else(Premium > 300, "high", "low")
  )

count_of_high <- sum(df_summary$high_low == "high")
label_for_graph <- paste("Count of High = ", count_of_high)

ggplot(df_summary, aes(x = Age, fill = high_low)) +
  geom_bar() +
  annotate("text", x = Inf, y = Inf, label = label_for_graph, hjust = 1.5, vjust = 2)
```

[image]